# Mi proyecto de asp.net c# se publica incompleto

Tags: c#, asp.net, sweetalert

En mi proyecto estoy usando una clase de SweetAlerts para mensajes de servidor
Pero al momento de publicar mi proyecto en mi servidor de IIS, estos mensajes no aparecen
Sin embargo cuando estoy haciendo pruebas en Visual Studio estos aparecen

Mi clase se llama UtilControls
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y así lo mando a llamar a mi Site.Master

```
<link href="/Content/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/Scripts/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Estos son los archivos que hay en el proyecto subido al IIS
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Saben de alguna razón por la cual este pasando esto?
Gracias de antemano!!!

Comment: Hola Luis, habría que ver como está desplegada tú proyecto, entiendo que en IIS?, puedes mostrar algo de esa info para ayudarte menjor?, en general creo que la ruta relativa /Scripts/sweetalert.min.js", no está donde debería.

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla Actualmente los archivos de mi proyecto que están en el iis son los de la imagen que subí arriba | Lo que he notado es que no veo por ninguna parte algún archivo de mi carpeta Útil

Comment: En el navegador, arroja algun error por consola?

Comment: @LuisVelazquez, si te refieres a que no ves el archivo UtilControls.cs, es porque se compila dentro de la dll de tú proyecto, bueno salvo pongas que se muestren las clases, entonces por lo que entiendo si ves el archivo sweetalert.min.js?, entonces debe ser un tema de ruteo, investiga por ahí, rutas, así mismo, puedes dentro de tú navegador, por ejemplo chrome, abrir la consola con F12 y ver si el recurso, osea el archivo sweetalert.min.js, no está cargando correctamente.

Comment: @Yussef arroja dos errores uno por cada archivo de Sweet Alerts css | js de que no fueron encontrados

Comment: Y están en las carpetas respectivas (en el servidor)??

Comment: @Yussef si y los archivos también están en ella

Comment: tienes otros archivos js y css en esas carpetas, los cuales si cargan?? si es asi favor muestra como están en el site.master.  Además, la url del sitio como es??

Comment: @Yussef no solo tengo esos archivos

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla amigo hice una prueba con una ruta diferente y ahora ya los puedo visualizar | Muchísimas gracias por el comentario

Comment: aahh que bueno!

Comment: @Yussef Amigo ya los pude visualizar, el detalle fue que mis rutas para encontrar los archivos al momento de publicarlo al servidor cambiaron he hice la prueba con un ruta nueva | Muchísimas gracias por tus comentarios

Comment: @LuisVelazquez  me alegro, te agradecería pudieras marcar la respuesta que pondré como la correcta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debe ser un tema de ruteo con tus archivos (específicamente el .js), investiga por ahí, sobre las rutas. Así mismo, puedes dentro de tú navegador, por ejemplo Chrome, abrir la consola con F12 y ver si el recurso, ósea el archivo sweetalert.min.js, no está cargando correctamente.